# Cookies does not get removed properly

Tags: php, cookies

To check what cookies exist i use this file (test.php):

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $value) {
    print $key . "=" . $value . "</br>";
}
```

I get the following output:

```
fbsr_{app id}={a bunch of chars}
```

(Where the stuff within {} are private data)

To remove all my sessions i use this:

```
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

And this to remove my cookies:

```
setcookie('fbsr_' . $app_id, $_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id], time() - 3600);
setcookie('PHPSESSID', $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'], time() - 3600);
unset($_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id]);   
unset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
```

Problem is when i run the code to check if my cookies are dead, they are not, and i get the same output :/

Why are my cookies not removed? Is my code bad somewhere? tried several browsers...

**EDIT:**
Seems like the cookies gets destroyed after all, but the test function still prints the cookie output?!?! im confused?!

(logout file)

```
if($action == 'logout'){

        $app_id = $facebook->getAppID();

        if (isset($_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id])) {
            echo 'goes here<br>';
            setcookie('fbsr_' . $app_id, $_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id], time() - 3600, "/");
            setcookie('PHPSESSID', $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'], time() - 3600, "/");
            unset($_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id]);   
            unset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
        }

        if (isset($_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id])) {
            echo 'is still sett<br>';
        }

        session_start();
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();

        $result = array("success" => "true");
    }
```

It never prints `is still sett` which means the cookie is deleted!

Thank you :)

Comment: Is the session destroyed before you call unset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])? At that point, if the session ID is blank then the cookie can't retrieve the ID and the cookie is then never unset because it isn't being referenced. If that's the case I'll put it in answer form once you confirm the session is being destroyed before the cookie is being unset.

Comment: Solved the issue for the PHPSESSID cookie, the other one still lives tho :/

Comment: Did you move the session_destroy() below your "setcookie" statements?

Comment: I sure did! Check out my question again, this is realy strange! I posted all the code there!

Comment: I'm going to need to see it straight out of the file to get any further on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a method I have used to remove cookies

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookieName'])) {
     setcookie('cookieName', '', time()-1);
}
```